# Encontrar foto no Drive

Tags: python, pillow

Criei um formulário do Forms do google onde recebo o upload de uma foto, e tenho um outro campo onde as pessoas descrevem a foto. A ideia é pegar essa descrição e inserir no metadado de descrição  da foto.
O meu problema é justamente conseguir selecionar a foto correta para inserir a informação.
O resultado do formulário do google gera um link onde minha foto foi armazenada,
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Porém eu não consegui achar um jeito de carregar a foto via este link o PIL, que são justamente as bibliotecas do python que uso para alterar a descrição da foto.

A foto carregada fica salva em uma pasta no google drive com o nome do arquivo original antes do upload + " - Nome do usuário'".

Abaixo deixo a parte do código que já implementei e serve de base para quando conseguir selecionar a foto certa para inseriri a descrição correspondente:

```
for x in listadefotos: #faz o looping por todos os arquivos encontrados no diretorio
  foto = '/content/drive/My Drive/Pictures/Teste/' + x  #cria string de acesso a foto, aqui devo selecionar a foto correta, acessando pelo nome da foto, mas eu não terei essa informação
  
  im = ImagePil.open(foto) #PARTE DO CÒDIGO ONDE PRECISO PUXAR A FOTO DO DRIVE VIA LINK do FORMULARIO
  
  descricao = {270:'teste de descricao'} # cria descrição, tag 270 refere-se a ImageDescription DEVE-SE IMPLEMENTAR ESTA PARTE DO CÓDIGO APRA RECEBER OS DADOS DO FORMULÁRIO
  
  exif_dict = {"0th":descricao} # adicona a descrição no modelo exigido pela bblioteca
  exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict) #cria forma de inserção dos dados que serão inseridos
  novolocal = "/content/drive/My Drive/Pictures/Processados/" + x 
  im.save(novolocal, exif=exif_bytes) #cria novo arquivo alterado com as descrições passadas
```

Comment: Os arquivos armazenado no google drive não possuem formatos "convencionas". Para baixar, você pode utilizar o `files.export` pela API do Google Drive para fazer os downloads.  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python_1

Comment: Mesmo baixando eu não conseguiria relacionar coma linha de informações do formulário. Se eu utilizar direto o caminho por dentro do drive eu consigo abrir a foto, o problema é que isso não serve na minha lógica, pois eu não vou saber qual é o nome da foto. Até poderia botar um campo no forms para que o usuário preenchesse como o nome original da foto, mas eu não consigo garantir que ele vai inserir corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi, você precisa que o PIL abra uma imagem que está em um link. Para tanto, acredito que a bilioteca `requests` associada ao PIL ajudaria nisso.

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

Exemplo retirado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python).

Espero que ajude.